# PhantomJS can't render fonts

Tags: fonts, phantomjs

I want to render a Website for creating a video afterwards with FFmpeg.

This is the code so far and the phantomjs command.

It actually works fine with a lot of websites, but I want to render an intranet website and I receive output like below.

What could be the reason for this incorrect rendering or am I missing something?

Thanks.

//EDIT 1: I think the problem is that, phantomjs has issues with fonts. Using verison 2.1.1

//EDIT 2: The same problem with https://developers.google.com/fonts/

```
//phantomjs capture.js http://www.stackoverflow.com C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/record/ 25

var args = require('system').args;
var url = args[1];
var path = args[2];
var frames = args[3];
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 640, height: 480 };

page.open(url, function () {
  setTimeout(function() {

    var frame = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
      // Render an image with the frame name
      page.render(path+(frame++)+'.png', { format: "png" });

      if(frame > 25) {
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }, frames);
  }, 666);
});
```

[image: Output]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- the issue with rendering https://developers.google.com/fonts/ or rather the common issues with the rendering function in phantomjs are are partial fixed in phantomjs 2.5.0 beta
- the first picture with the strange symbolics is based on missing fonts. Phantom is running on Redhat without a core set of fonts. So I installed some TTF.

  1. create Folder:  `/usr/share/fonts/TTF`
  2. put all your TTF files in there and run `fc-cache -f -v`

Comment: or in any directory and run `fc-cache -f -v /fonts_dir/`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Japanese, Chinese, Hindi or other special characters, I was having a problem with phantomjs and rendering of fonts for these special characters, and that's how I solved the problem:

1. Download the corresponding `.ttf` [Unicode fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) file. There are several free sites on the web, but you have several Unicode fonts free files for several different character maps [here](http://www.fonts2u.com/category.html?id=92).
2. Save the `.ttf` files in your server/machine either in the directory `/etc/fonts` or in the directory `~/.fonts`. The latter is also a unix directory, if it does not exist, create it, and you need it if you have no root privileges (shared server for example)
3. Run either `fc-cache -fv /etc/fonts` or `fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts/` accordingly. This [fc-cache](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-cache) command scans the font directories on the system and builds font information cache files

Then in the phantomjs code, use always `utf-8` either for **file system**

```
var HTMLfile = fs.open(path + file_name, {
    mode: 'r', //read
    charset: 'utf-8' 
});
var content = HTMLfile.read();
HTMLfile.close();
```

or for **webpage**

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var settings = {
  operation: "POST",
  encoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    some: "data",
    another: ["custom", "data"]
  })
};
```

After long search, it worked for me.